# Simple C++ error, "else without previous if"

Tags: c++

I'm just getting started with C++ and I've run into an error. It tells me that I have an "else" without a previous "If", but I do. I checked the case of the code and it looks basically just like the example from the website I'm learning from, it just has different sentences after all the couts, so I don't know what's wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
int main()
{
int iOud;

cout<<"Type in your age: ";
cin >> iOud;  //"a variable for the person's age
cin.ignore();
if (iOud < 20 );{
  cout<< "A message\n";
}
else if (iOud > 40 ) {
  cout << "A message\n";
}
else {
  cout << "A message\n";
}
cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `;` after `if (iOud < 20)` terminates the `if` statement.

Drop it, and you'd be fine

Answer (score 8):

Drop the `;` from `if (iOud < 20 );{`

`if (iOud < 20 );` *is* a valid statement, so the compiler does not emit an error until it finds the invalid `} else if`. That's why the compiler error appears odd on first inspection.

Answer (score 4):

You ended the `if(...)` sentence with `;` so it doesn't recognize it at all it, just sees the `else if` and drops the error. Drop the `;` at `if (iOud < 20 ); {`.

And may I recommend using `Switch/Case`, if you are using multiple `if` sentences, but as **Sean** mentioned in the comment, this wouldn't apply for your example of comparing range of values.

Comment: `switch/case` wouldn't work well here as he's comparing a range of values (using `<` and `>`) rather than looking for discrete values (using `==`).

Comment: Yes true, I was talking more in general sense, but thanks for clearing that out.